# Merging a temp_table into another table based on non-primary key

Tags: mysql, join, merge, primary-key

I have a CSV file that I upload with multiple rows.
Each time I upload it, I store it in a table called '**tempTable**', the primary key, 'file_number' does not exist in 'tempTable'.
My function checks it with a table called '**inputTable**'.

**file_number** is the primary key, which is created using uuid()

The **tempTable** contents have a column, **input_street**.
I need to compare the tempTable **input_street** key with the **inputTable** **input_street** key.

If the same input_street exists then I need to merge the specific row of tempTable values into inputTable, if any changes exist in the rest of the columns.

But if it's a new input_street (they don't match), it should create a new row in the 'inputTable' with a new file_number using UUID().

I am using MYSQL on Python. The main catch is that I **must** compare against a non-primary key 'input_street'. If 'input_street' is the same in both, then columns must be updated otherwise create a new row in 'inputTable'.

My current code is as such:

```
INSERT INTO inputTable (
    file_number, input_street, ...
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(inputTable.file_number, UUID()) AS file_number,
    temp_table.input_street, ...
FROM
    inputTable
LEFT JOIN
    temp_table ON inputTable.input_street = temp_table.input_street
```

**EDIT**

I have added a file_number column to the tempTable using UUID()

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a unique key in the table inputTable (if it doesn't already exist) and then you can easily use

**INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;**.

This appends new rows and updates existing ones

**sample**

```
INSERT INTO inputTable
  SELECT * from tmp_inputTable
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b = VALUES(b);
```

see Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Unique key exists in inputTable.
but it does not exist in tempTable.

I need to compare the table based on non-primary keys.